# Is the black egg on House's desk a reference to Tesla's 'Egg of Columbus'?

Tags: props, house

Is the black egg on House's desk a reference to Tesla's '[Egg of Columbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_of_Columbus)'?

[image: dr House office stuff meaning]e 
Image from [here](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2010/04/18/article-1267059-000C5BD5000004B0-834_468x300.jpg).

Comment: What does this have to do with the TV show "Office Space"? Please avoid using tags without understanding what the tags are for.

Comment: But the tag "office space" is to be used **only** for the film with that name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space

Comment: Please do not rollback edits that actually corrected errors in the question.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/14641/16465) answer to the question [**Why does House have an old TV in his office?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/12579/16465)

> There is no particular significance to any item in his office or apartment